# Contact form throws errors when sending an email.

Tags: php

**I am developing a contact form for sending an email to user data,but its not working.**

**Code:**

```
<?php
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') {
    $ToEmail = 'youremail@site.com';
    $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form';
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
?>
Your message was sent
<?php
} else {
?>
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="29%" class="bodytext">Your name:</td>
<td width="71%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Email address:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="32"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext">Comment:</td>
<td><textarea name="Comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="Comment" class="bodytext"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bodytext"> </td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
};
?>
```

It throws an errors like:

- Undefined index: commen in line 10.
- header missing in line 11.

Comment: I am quite sure these are _not_ errors but notices or warnings instead. The first one is obvious: `$_POST["comment"]` does not exist. You have to test if it does before using it. The second one sounds odd, yould you please paste the _real_ output you get?

Comment: `$_POST["comment"]` to `$_POST["Comment"]`

Comment: AFTER done this also having warning header missing..

Answer (score 3):

Here are some mistakes on your code..

1.at the line no 2 change the code from (i don't know why you didn't mention about this error)

```
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"]<>'') {
```

2.change the name of the textarea from "Comment" to "comment"

and finally follow the instruction from the previous answers of this post to solve the "header missing" problem.
something like

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

As everybody told your first mistake, I am not going to repeat it but another mistake is:

You should join the mail headers and mail body:

Your previous code:

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
```

New Code:

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";
```

Look at the dots given before the equalto signs.

Answer (score 0):

see you need to concatenate the mailHeader var same goes for body message

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have done the two mistakes.**

1. In form you have given **`name="Comment"`** for please give **`name="comment"`    or          $_POST["comment"] to $_POST["Comment"]**
2. put the **.** after `mail header`.like

   $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";

   $mailheader **.**= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";

   $mailheader **.**= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

   $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";

   $MESSAGE_BODY **.**= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";

   $MESSAGE_BODY **.**= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."";

Comment: Your answer is wrong, the dots should be immediately before the equalto sign, one space should not be there between them. eg: not $abc. = abc but $abc .= abc

Comment: thats my type mistake

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error 10th line because you are using **$_POST["comment"]"** but in the form you have written **id="Comment"**. To remove the error take care of upar and lower case in the both places..

Thank you.